# How to route map-like parameters in GET request with Play

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have to handle the following GET request in my Play application eg.

```
http://host/somemethod?queries[search]=asdf&perPage=100&sorts[name]=0
```

Now, normally GET requests like:

```
http://host/somemethod?queries=asdf&perPage=100&sorts=0
```

can be easily handled with eg.

```
GET         /somemethod     controllers.SomeMethodController.getPeople(queries:String ?= "", perPage: Int ?= 10, sorts:String ?= "")
```

but the params like: `queries[search]=asdf` or `sorts[name]=0` are not resolved properly 
(tried simple `String` type, `Seq[String]` or `Map[String,String]` - the last one throws exception about missing `QueryStringBinder`)

How do I map those query params to a method parameters with Play routing? Do I need to create my own custom `QueryStringBinder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Maps are not supported by the default QueryString binder and you therefor should implement your own `QueryStringBindable`. The [Javadoc of QueryStringBindable](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/java/play/mvc/QueryStringBindable.html) should give you a hint how to implement it.

Play 2.x supports the following query string parameter types:

- String
- Char
- Int
- Integer (Java)
- Long (Scala and Java)
- Double (Scala and Java)
- Float (Scala and Java)
- Boolean (Scala and Java)
- java.util.UUID
- Option
- Optional (Java)
- Seq
- List (Scala and Java)
- Array

See [Binders.scala](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/8b6c8242a8e923d25bba40b902a84398ab1cc178/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Binders.scala) for all supported types.